How to use Rails and Hotwire Turbo Streaming to Stream a Long Page?
I looked at https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams and https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails/turbo-streams , but did not see quite how to do this.
I have a long page that many messages. When the page loads, it should stream the messages. Suppose there are 100 messages and it takes 100ms to render each message. The user should see 1 message each 100ms so that they are rendered as they are streamed.
On the index page there would be a target id:
<div id="messages"></div>

It seems there would be a message partial:
<turbo-stream action="append" target="messages">
  <template>
    <turbo-frame id="message">
      <%= message.text %>
    </turbo-frame>
  </template>
</turbo-stream>

It seems that the controller might look like:
@messages = Message.last(100)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
  end

  format.turbo_stream do
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(:messages, partial: 'message',
      locals: { collection: @messages })
  end
end

Not sure if the whole page is streaming or only the messages would be streaming.
If the whole page is streaming, then I gather you must force Rails to render a turbo_stream with out a streaming request. But not sure how to target the _top frame.
If only the messages are streaming, then it seems we need a mechanism to start the streaming upon the rendering of the index page. Not sure if there is a JS Turbo command to do this...
Please do not tell me that this is the wrong thing to do. I know that it is a bad idea to stream many messages. This is simplified example of the use case. This simplified example makes it easier comprehend without adding additional context.
EDIT: Rails 7.1.2

You're not doing the wrong thing but you're thinking about it wrong. The whole idea of decomposition is to give the impression of the page loading faster as the user can interact with the page faster even if it actually takes longer in total before everything is loaded and rendered. What I don't understand is why you think you should be targeting the _top frame as that will trigger a re-render of the entire page.

Note that on its own turbo stream is not a streaming response, it's just a regular http/html. You could make your own Turbo channel and stream from that:
# app/channels/messages_channel.rb

class MessagesChannel < Turbo::StreamsChannel
  def subscribed
    super

    Message.last(100).each do |message|
      MessagesChannel.broadcast_append_to(
        verified_stream_name_from_params,
        target: "messages",
        partial: "messages/message",
        locals: {message:}
      )
    end
  end
end

# app/views/messages/_message.html.erb

<%= tag.div id: dom_id(message) do %>
  <%= message.text %>
<% end %>

In your template:
<%= turbo_stream_from "messages", channel: "MessagesChannel" %>

<div id="messages"></div>


turbo stream is not a streaming response - I realized this after posting. I gather it will broadcast each message individually, so that would work as well.

I have implemented an approach in a portfolio social media app project for infinite scrolling of posts on timeline and profile pages using Turbo frames and Turbo Streams.
First, let's lazy load posts from controller in Turbo format. I am also using 'will-paginate' gem for pagination. The logic here is in 2nd turbo frame tag where we lazy load posts again if we have any posts left (if next page). Lazy loading only happens when this component becomes visible on screen.
<%# app/views/timeline/index.html.erb %>
      <%= turbo_frame_tag "posts", src: root_path(format: :turbo_stream), loading: :lazy %>
      <% if @posts.next_page %>
        <%= turbo_frame_tag "load_more", src: root_path(page: @posts.next_page, format: :turbo_stream), loading: :lazy %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-8">
      <p class="text-gray-500"> Current page: <span id="current_page"><%= @posts.current_page %></span></p>
    </div> 

So, when we get turbo stream response, we append post to posts and replace load_more turbo frame with next page as parameter so when user scrolls further down and this load_more becomes visible, it loads more posts and process repeats
<%# app/views/timeline/index.turb_stream.erb %>
<%= turbo_stream.append "posts" do %>
  <%= render partial: "posts/post", collection: @posts %>
<% end %>
<% if @posts.next_page %>
  <%= turbo_stream.replace "load_more" do %>
    <%= turbo_frame_tag "load_more", src: root_path(page: @posts.next_page, format: :turbo_stream), loading: :lazy %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= turbo_stream.update "current_page", @posts.current_page %>

On controller side, we are just loading posts with pagination and page parameter
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    friend_ids = current_user.friends.pluck(:id)
    friend_ids << current_user.id
    # @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1).order('created_at DESC')
    @posts = Post.where(user_id: friend_ids).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1).order('created_at DESC')
  end
end

In this way, we can load huge amounts of data on page with lazy loading and infinite scrolling without any line of JavaScript code.
